# DotNet CLI: Restore Nuget package without adding to project

Tags: .net-core, nuget, teamcity

We build our `dotnet` artifacts on a TeamCity server and want to include the [SqlPackage.CommandLine](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SqlPackage.CommandLine/) binaries alongside our build output. Running `dotnet add package SqlPackage.CommandLine` yields "Could not find any projects in C:\build". Can someone recommend a way to grab the nuget output without adding it to a project?

Comment: Is downloading it directly from NuGet (https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/SqlPackage.CommandLine/14.0.3953.4) via command line an option?

Comment: Trying to do it in a version independent way in case the version in the URL changes, so that is something I'm trying to avoid unless you can suggest a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just download the NuGet package directly from `nuget.org`: `curl -O -L https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/SqlPackage.CommandLine` does the trick and downloads the latest version.

If you need the contents from that package, you can simply unarchive it with zip utils afterwards